# Unity3d TextMeshPro create external font asset runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, fonts

I am creating a tool that users will be able to create their own contents(like powerpoint)and that content will be played in IOS Tablets. However, users should be able to load their own fonts to use in their texts in runtime. It's not available in Unity <2018.2. But I wonder if it is available on TextMeshPro since its using font assets created by their own.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately there appears to be a big process, vaugely outlined at https://forum.unity.com/threads/creating-tmp_fontasset-at-runtime.550426/  this would be too broad for SO as the question stands.

Comment: Struggling with materials and bitmaps are not good for user experience I think.